# I need to find SonarQube pluging that integrates NodeJs with AWS Code Pipeline

Tags: node.js

I have nodeJs application code in my code commit and am using Codebuild to deploy my code using Cloudformation, I need to use SonarQube for code quality check,I need the plugin and ways to install and use it in AWS CodePipeline

Comment: which build tool you are using

Comment: am using CodeBuild